# Debug Insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server

I've written the code to create a table and insert information from the Products table into the ProductsAudit table. My problem is that when I insert data into the Products table I get an error that tells me the DateUpdated column does not allow NULL values. I'm trying to insert GETDATE() and can't figure out what is causing the problem.

```
USE MyGuitarshop

GO

CREATE TABLE ProductsAudit(
    AuditID         int         PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ProductID       int         NOT NULL,
    CategoryID      int         NOT NULL,
    ProductCode     varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    ProductName     varchar(255)NOT NULL,
    ListPrice       money       NOT NULL,
    DiscountPercent money       NOT NULL,
    DateUpdated     datetime2   NOT NULL);

GO

CREATE TRIGGER ProductsAudit_UPDATE
    ON Products
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS

   INSERT INTO 
        ProductsAudit (ProductID, CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, DateUpdated)
           SELECT 
              Products.ProductID, 
              Products.CategoryID, 
              Products.ProductCode, 
              Products.ProductName, 
              Products.ListPrice, 
              Products.DiscountPercent, 
              DateAdded AS DateUpdated
          FROM Products


GO

INSERT INTO
    Products (CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, Description, ListPrice,DiscountPercent, DateAdded)
        Values
            (1, '229715', 'Sushi', 'Great food for hungry students', 9.99, 12, GETDATE());

GO

USE MyGuitarShop

SELECT * FROM ProductsAudit
```

Comment: Your insert is doing an inner join on the table it's inserting to.. why?

Comment: Because that's where the AuditID information is coming from? Does it not need to be doing a JOIN?

Comment: Well, you just created that table - is there anything in it?

Comment: No, it is an empty table. I've removed the JOIN and the AuditID from the insert statement and am testing it now.

Comment: I think you may want to make AuditID an `identity` column - so you get automatically generated values

Comment: Okay, taking AuditID from the table pulls up an error saying the AuditID column does not allow nulls. Looks like that one has to be in there.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Making that column an Identity helped fix that issue. Now it's popping that the DateUpdated column does not allow NULL values. I've changed  the insert to GETDATE(), but it's still saying it doesn't allow NULL values.

Comment: I posted an answer, can you see if it helps?

Comment: I saw that after I posted and, yes, it was wonderful. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I was about ready to scream in frustration. Now I understand better how this is supposed to work. Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want `AuditID` to be an `identity` column:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductsAudit(
    AuditID         int         IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
```

And once you've done that, you don't need to specify that column in the insert. You also probably meant to use `getdate()` for `DateUpdated`, especially since you're inserting null into the `DateAdded` column of `Product`.

```
INSERT INTO 
    ProductsAudit (ProductID, CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, DateUpdated)
       SELECT 
          ProductID, 
          CategoryID, 
          ProductCode, 
          ProductName, 
          ListPrice, 
          DiscountPercent, 
          GetDate() AS DateUpdated
      FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Thank you so much for your help. I've had three of these problems I've been working on since 7am and you've helped me figure out what was wrong with this one. Now there's just two left. Thank you so much. That worked wonderfully.

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, you can mark this answer as "correct" by clicking the check mark beside it.